# Using python module 'lxml' in Apache Nifi

Tags: python, apache, jython, apache-nifi

I have written a python script to run in NiFi processor 'ExecuteScript'. I have 'lxml' module installed but when I run the processor it throws an error saying that 'cannot import  name etree'. Is there anyway I can use the lxml module in Nifi?

Comment: The only thing that's changed since then is [jyni](https://jyni.org/). There's no indication that it does support lxml, but it's possible that it might. Otherwise you're out of luck I think.

Comment: (I do now realise that you've already seen that question so it may not be too helpful but unfortunately it's most likely still the answer)